# Target new customers using old customer data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I have two tables.

1. Old customers data which includes transaction data.
2. New customer data with no transaction data.
   I need to model the data to recommend which of the customers from the new customer table to be targeted.

The process I followed.

1. RFM segmentation on old customer data and classified the customers into 11 categories.
2. Since most data is of string type, converted to numeric by LabelEncoder().
3. Old Customer data is split into X train(3492,12) and X test(3492,)
4. New customer data is just Ytrain(983,12). The values in brackets are its shape.
5. Performing KNN algorithm.

Please suggest if the process is correct
Also I am encountering the following errors.

```
train_cols = ['address', 'state', 'gender', 'job_title', 'job_industry_category', 'wealth_segment', 'owns_car', 'Title']
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
enc = LabelEncoder()
for col in train_cols:
  Training[col] = Training[col].astype('str')
  Training[col] = enc.fit_transform(Training[col])
//Training is the old customer data

test_cols = ['address', 'state', 'gender', 'job_title', 'job_industry_category', 'wealth_segment', 'owns_car']
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
enc = LabelEncoder()
for col in test_cols:
  Test[col] = Test[col].astype('str')
  Test[col] = enc.fit_transform(Test[col])
//Test is the new customer data

Xtrain = Xtrain.transpose(); Ytrain = Ytrain.transpose()
//shape - Xtrain = (12,3492), Ytrain = (12,983)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
classifier.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)

y_pred = classifier.predict(Xtest)
```

Error:

```
//ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-8ae3ac010601> in <module>()
----> 1 y_pred = classifier.predict(Xtest)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    554                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    555                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 556                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    557 
    558         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[10  2  3 ...  4  0  3].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

The model is trained but unable to predict. I am unable to reshape it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the shape of the array and the issue is solved:

```
Xtest = Xtest.reshape(1,-1)
```

I am not sure why (-1,1) does not work.